# How to accepting negative floating numbers with TextBox UWP?

Tags: c#, uwp

I have a requirement.

1) Accept positive and negative floating numbers

2) Accept numbers values that represent latitude,longitude coordinates.

From the answers already posted I got how to accept positive floating numbers

```
private void floatTextBox_TextChanging(TextBox sender, TextBoxTextChangingEventArgs args)
{
    try
    {
        if (!Regex.IsMatch(sender.Text, "^\\d*\\.?\\d*$") && sender.Text != "")
        {
            int pos = sender.SelectionStart - 1;
            sender.Text = sender.Text.Remove(pos, 1);
            sender.SelectionStart = pos;
        }
    }
    catch
    {
    }
}
```

I wanted to know how to accept negative numbers as adding a **^\-** to the beginning of expression is not working.
Also I tried the other answers here but none worked even with the coordinates.

Comment: why you are checking the value on textchanged event? you can do that after taking the complete value of the textBox.

Comment: You mean first let user input any data and then decide whether its right or not? But I thought it would be better not to let user input wrong data in the first place

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this one

```
@"^[-]?[0-9]*(?:\.[0-9]*)?$"
```

Comment: This pattern will match an empty string.

Comment: @AbsoluteSith sorry I am not clear about your comment

Answer (score 0):

Instead of regex, I'd use something along these lines in your case:

```
float f;
if (float.TryParse(sender.Text, out f))
{
    // Do stuff
}
```

This will get you positive and negative floating numbers.

Comment: This probably wouldn't work with TextChanging event handler, as a standalone negative symbol would not satisfy this condition

Comment: No, a standalone negative symbol wouldn't satisfy the condition. Why should it?

Comment: So how do you assume I would evaluate a negative number on the TextChanging event while trying to parse it as a float?

Comment: how about if (f < 0)